# Checkboxes in html5

Tags: html, checkbox

I need to add a section of code to a website. Using html5, I've added checkboxes with a submit button below to the website. I want to make it that in order to advance to the next page, one MUST first click the checkbox and then click the submit button. Currently, if the user DOES NOT click the checkbox, then the user is be able to advance to the next page. This should NOT happen. If the user does not click the checkbox, then the user should not advance to the next page. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Accessories</h1>

<form name="input" action="random2_action.asp" method="get"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">Would you like the car to speak to you?<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

If someone could tell me how to fix this, that would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's not possible in pure HTML, you must use javascript validation. You can do it yourself or use one of many validation plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `required` attribute is really useful in situations like this;

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" required>Would you like the car to speak to you?<br /><br />
```

Check my fiddle for a live demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/magnusburton/fUskV/

**EDIT:**
This won't work if the browser doesn't support HTML5. Here's a solution which works for the majority of the users.

[Simple JavaScript Checkbox Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234622/simple-javascript-checkbox-validation)

Comment: Just a side note, this will fail if user is on an older browser.. So if it's very important function, you should use server side validation or atleast JS valition(Which will also fail if user disables JavaScript)

Comment: That is absolutely true! I keep forgetting that some people use a pretty outdated browser. I've found another solution which seems to work fine. Updated answer!