# JavaScript Function to validate checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, function, validation, checkbox

I'm trying to not allow both checkboxes to be checked at the same time. Here is my vanilla JS. I have the function already validating to return true when one is checked and false when neither are checked. Radio boxes are not an option.

```js
function valForm() {
  var both = document.getElementById("cEmail1" & "cPhone1");
  for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById("cEmail1").checked) {
      return true;
    } else if (document.getElementById("cPhone1").checked) {
      return true;
    } else if (both.checked) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="http://severien.com/grit/formecho.php" method="post" name="contactUsForm" onsubmit="return valForm()">
  <span class="box3"><label for="cEmail" class="l5" >Contact me by email</label>
  <input class="check1" id="cEmail1" type="checkbox" name="contactbyemail"  /></span>
  <span class="box4"><label for="cPhone" class="l6">Contact me by phone</label>
  <input class="check2" id="cPhone1" type="checkbox" name="contactbyphone"  /></span> <br />
  <div class="formSubmit"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
</form>
```

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234622/simple-javascript-checkbox-validation

Comment: why not using radio button?

Comment: why not use radio buttons ??

Comment: Radio boxes does exactly what you want. Why are radio boxes not an option though?

Comment: I agree that this would be a logical first option. But I was given parameters specifically not to use radio buttons...

Comment: `else if (document.getElementById("cEmail1").checked && document.getElementById("cPhone1").checked) {` seems to be the most logical bit of code to use.

Answer (score 3):

If radio boxes really aren't an option, then there are a few issues with your code. First of all, you are checking if each of the boxes is checked, and if either of them is checked, then you are immediately returning. The second, and much larger problem, is that your `both` element should be undefined. The `&` in JavaScript is a bitwise operator, and `getElementById` should only return one element. Instead, you could implement the equivalent of a logical XOR like so:

```
function valForm(){
     return document.getElementById("cEmail1").checked != document.getElementById("cPhone1").checked; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get two elements at the same time using `getElementById`, so you'll need to check them separately by using the `&&` operator.

You also need to check this first, because the two `if` statements before this will preempt this check.

```js
function valForm() {
  var cEmail = document.getElementById("cEmail1");
  var cPhone1 = document.getElementById("cPhone1");
  if (cEmail.checked && cPhone1.checked) {
    console.log("false");
    return false;
  } else if (cEmail.checked || cPhone1.checked) {
    console.log("true");
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log("false");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="http://severien.com/grit/formecho.php" method="post" name="contactUsForm" onsubmit="return valForm()">
  <span class="box3"><label for="cEmail" class="l5" >Contact me by email</label>
  <input class="check1" id="cEmail1" type="checkbox" name="contactbyemail"  /></span>
  <span class="box4"><label for="cPhone" class="l6">Contact me by phone</label>
  <input class="check2" id="cPhone1" type="checkbox" name="contactbyphone"  /></span> <br />
  <div class="formSubmit"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should return false if neither or both are checked:

```js
function valForm() {
  var email = document.getElementById("cEmail1");
  var phone = document.getElementById("cPhone1")
  if (email.checked && !phone.checked || !email.checked && phone.checked) {
    console.log('ok')
    return true;
  }
  console.log('no ok')
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="http://severien.com/grit/formecho.php" method="post" name="contactUsForm" onsubmit="return valForm()">


  <span class="box3"><label for="cEmail" class="l5" >Contact me by email</label>
<input class="check1" id="cEmail1" type="checkbox" name="contactbyemail"  /></span>
  <span class="box4"><label for="cPhone" class="l6">Contact me by phone</label>
<input class="check1" id="cPhone1" type="checkbox" name="contactbyphone"  /></span> <br />
  <div class="formSubmit"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.slectOne').on('change', function() {
   $('.slectOne').not(this).prop('checked', false);
   $('#result').html($(this).data( "id" ));
   if($(this).is(":checked"))
    $('#result').html($(this).data( "id" ));
   else
    $('#result').html('Empty...!');
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="1 selected"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="2 selected"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="3 selected"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="4 selected"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="5 selected"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="6 selected"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="7 selected"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="8 selected"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="9 selected"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="10 selected"/>
<span id="result"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

here is a good example to use as well
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FB6JK5HW3Z53

Comment: This question is not about a jQuery approach.

Comment: well use it, its the best approach